# Android: How do I stop my edit text from going to next one?

Tags: android

so i have a login form. When i press the back button or the enter button, it seems to go the next edit text (or previous) even though i set these following options for my edit text.

What is weird, once i cycle through them all, everything works fine as it should i.e. back button / done button dismiss the edit text and key board.

Please note i am only showing 1 edit text field to not flood the post. The rest are pretty much the same

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <com.test.views.widgets.myEditText
                        android:id="@+id/userFirstName"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/generic.first.name"
                        android:inputType="textPersonName"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:theme="@style/EditText.Base.Style"
                        app:font="regular" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

So the above, i have set actionDone which was one of the suggestions to this problem. This does not work.

In addition, I am extending the AppCompatEditText to have my own implementation.

Here is some code 
When done button is pressed

```
  @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
                clearFocus();
            }
            return false;
        }
```

When the back button is pressed

```
 @Override
    public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            clearFocus();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Also note that i followed this tutorial as a means to hide keyboard when focus changes

http://toastdroid.com/2015/06/04/on-screen-keyboard-tracking-part-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this.

I added this to my root layout (which contained the edit text) and the problem no longer seems present

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Answer (score 2):

Add android:imeOptions="actionDone". It will close keyboard rather than going on next focusable view.

Answer (score 1):

add this to the EditText attribute

```
 android:maxLines="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` to your `EditText`

OR

```
youredittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int keyCode,
        KeyEvent event) {
     if ( (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN  ) &&
         (keyCode           == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)   )
    {               
       // hide virtual keyboard
       InputMethodManager imm = 
          (InputMethodManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
       imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edittext.getWindowToken(), 0);
       return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Try using "android:singleLine=true"

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that problem is in your `clearFocus()`. Documentation [says](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#clearFocus()):

> Note: When a View clears focus the framework is trying to give focus
>   to the first focusable View from the top. Hence, if this View is the
>   first from the top that can take focus, then all callbacks related to
>   clearing focus will be invoked after which the framework will give
>   focus to this view.

try to replace `clearFocus()` with `hideKeyboard()` like this

```
void hideKeyboard()    {
((InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(yourView.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```